# updating unique field values django creates a new row

Tags: python, django

I have a model which has a field with unique constraint. When I try to update the unique field value, a new row is created instead of updating the old one. Did refer to few other queries but couldnt find a solution. Below is my model :

```
class AircraftType(models.Model):
    aircraft_id = models.AutoField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    aircraft_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    aircraft_description = models.TextField()
```

and my views.py :

```
def save_aircrafts(request):
    print "save_aircrafts"
    aircraft_type = request.POST.get('aircrafttype')
    print str("Save aircraft_type ") + aircraft_type
    aircraft_instance = AircraftType.objects.filter(aircraft_type=aircraft_type)
    if aircraft_instance.exists():
        print str("aircraft_instance.exists") + aircraft_type
        aircraft_instance.update(aircraft_type=aircraft_type)
        aircraft_instance.aircraft_type = aircraft_type
        aircraft_instance.save()
    else:
        print str("aircraft_instance.NOTexists") + aircraft_type
        AircraftType.objects.create(aircraft_type=aircraft_type)
    return redirect('aircraft_list')
```

I am calling my `save_aircrafts` method from my html file.

Comment: You can't ever be getting into the `if` block, because you would be getting a NameError: the thing that you have confusingly called `aircraft_instance` is in fact not an instance, but a QuerySet, and those don't have a `save` method. So you must *always* be going into the `else` block: presumably, because the value you are using for `aircrafttype` is *not* already in the database. What do your print statements show?

Comment: @Daniel exists() is a valid method on filtered querysets.  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists though your point about the save method not being available is correct.

Comment: Yes I didn't say it wasn't. `exists` *only* works on querysets, that is not the problem at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - Thanks a ton!. You were right on going to the else block. `aircraft_instance.update(aircraft_type=aircraft_type)` alone worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `get_or_create` function,

```
aircraft_instance, created = AircraftType.objects.get_or_create(aircraft_type=aircraft_type)
if created:
    print "New object has been created"
else:
    #Do what you want to do with instance.
    aircraft_instance.save()
```